# CRLF causes read() from socket to return

Tags: sockets, http, newline, recv

I'm writing an HTTP server in C++, using a TCP socket to communicate between client and server.

While sending a request to the server using my Linux terminal, I've noticed that each time I press `Enter`, the `read()` on my server returns (it reads up to the `\r\n` and returns).

Is this behavior "normal" ? I have not found it mentionned anywhere.

EDIT: I'm using telnet as client and a blocking read/recv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blocking `read` or `recv` returns whenever data are available. If you enter `Enter` on *whatever you use on the terminal as client* (i.e. netcat, telnet or similar) it will likely (depending on the actual client) directly send this `\r\n` to the server where it will cause an immediate successful return of `read`/`recv`.

Comment: So `Enter` sends a signal that some data is available ?
Edit: I'm using telnet, and I've noticed this behavior using either a blocking or a non blocking socket.

Comment: `Enter` causes telnet to send the data.  The arrival of that data at the server causes `read()` to return.

Comment: Can we consider that a "normal" HTTP client will have this behavior ? 
Or should my server be prepared for a request that arrives entirely in one shot (instead of line by line) for example ?

Comment: @Grim you should be prepared for a request that arrives one byte at a time.

Comment: @Grim: Your server should not make any kind of assumptions about how data are read. Request header and body can be in single or separate packets or even half the request might be in one packet, rest of header and body in another. TCP is just a byte stream, not a message protocol. And specifically - a `recv` on one side does not need to match a `send` on the other. All what counts is the bytes at the end, no matter how exactly they were send and received.